# Android ViewPager as a project module?

Tags: android, module, android-viewpager

I need significantly change `ViewPager` default behaviour (I need to have first dummy tab and on scroll to it open `navigation drawer`).
As I researched, it's possible only when I'll change `ViewPager's` private methods, such as `performDrag()` etc.

Is there a way to download `ViewPager` (or maybe `core-ui` part of `support` library) as a separate module of the project? Tried a lot, but no luck at the moment.

Comment: create your own implementation of Viewpager and use reflection api to access private fields/methods

Comment: I tried to, but some fields even after `setAccessible(true)` are not modifiable. Moreover, there is a big amount of such fields, that's why having it as a separate module would be much preferable.